# mediaObject response in actions-on-google v2?

Tags: actions-on-google

mediaObject response is not working, without any error in logs

```
 conv.ask(new MediaObject({
        name: channel.name,
        url: channel.stream_url,
        description: `Regional`,
        })
    }));
```

Comment: you played live audio or just mp3 audio?

Comment: I have used mp3, this issue was resolved by adding a suggestion in the flow, which I missed somehow.

Comment: If you are wondering, how to play a live stream, I have tested that if the live stream is in mp3 format, it works just fine. But in the documentation it says "not allowed" for the live stream audio.

Comment: i am using php, how to add suggestion in . response model using v2 dialogflow api? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [official document](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#asdk_node_media_response), it says

> Your Action must include suggestion chips if the response is not a
>   final response.

This might be the case for you, try including suggestion chips also

```
conv.ask(new Suggestions(['Suggestion1', 'Suggestion2']));
```

Comment: yes, you are right, I did manage to find and solve the issue, but thanks for the answer!